# How to hide show desktop icons in Windows using Java

Tags: java, windows, swing, icons, jna

I would like to know how to hide/show OS desktop icons ([like this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3659-desktop-icons-hide-show.html)) in windows using a Java swing app (for instance clicking a button). I check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402834/how-to-hide-desktop-icons-programatically) it's with C#, I thought use JNA, but I don't have idea how to start.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to hide the OS desktop icons or the `JDesktopPane` icons??

Comment: @MadProgrammer Tag `jna` answers your question.

Comment: Note that if your app. put them there using the JNLP API, it is possible to remove them using the same API.  Otherwise, if they don't belong to your app. you probably shouldn't be hiding desktop icons (at least, not using Java).

Comment: Not a very informative question. Please give us the details of your problem so we don't have to guess.

Comment: @M.M. Given how many errant tags get added to questions, that's not always the case ;)

Comment: I'm trying to hide OS desktop icon [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3659-desktop-icons-hide-show.html) but I want to do from a swing app (using a button)

Comment: OK, so what have you tried, and what isn't working?

Comment: I check this with [C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402834/how-to-hide-desktop-icons-programatically) I thought to use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna), but I don't have idea how to start.

Comment: Icons on the taskbar(of iconified frames), if so what should it do with the frame. Or of files and folders?

Comment: @M.M. I try to do [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3659-desktop-icons-hide-show.html) but using a swing app, click a button and hide/show desktop OS icons.

Comment: @Jeff: no, you don't want to do with a Swing app, at least not yet. For any programming project the key is to divide and conquer. **First** do it with JNA in a very simple console app, and only when you've got that debugged should you worry about doing something this (in a background thread of course) in a Swing application. Do not over-complicate your problem lest it becomes insurmountable. And I speak from experience because I have created quite a few Swing apps that use JNA.

Answer (score 1):

Yoy probably should use regedit to hide or show it, i do not code on java but the path to key is Компьютер\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced HideIcons.

Comment: i just noticed this question created 11 years ago...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).