# to hide the block the desktop during my startup program launch

Tags: startup

i am develop a application based on log in and log out for my students. when my user logged in, the start up application will be load. during the start up!

My Question : all my desktop icon and other application should be disabled when my start up application load.Any one suggested me i really owe to you guys.

Comment: what are you developing your appicantion in and what operating system are you running?

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?  Here is an example of C#:
[How to hide desktop icons programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402834/how-to-hide-desktop-icons-programatically)

anyway you can use the windows API with C# or C++ don't know about java. Try and see if it works.

Comment: actually my code is C# vs 2005 and my Win7 os @zedd..
now i find my solution for my problem., here my code is 
i work with registrykey for my application :
** RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows
\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);**
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
// Add the value in the registry so that the application runs at startup
rkApp.SetValue("MyApp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());               
}
else
{
 // Remove the value from the registry so that the application doesn't start
 rkApp.DeleteValue("MyApp", false);